# unable to reach C:\Program file in command line

Tags: android, windows, command-line, command-prompt

We are on a task to convert our unsigned apk to signed one through command line. In that endeavour, we needed to reach to Java SDK folder to create key. Unfortunately when we type the path in command line (C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin). There is error popping out: Too Many Parameters - Files. We also tried to reach path C:\Program Files only but still same error displayed.

Any solution to this problem ?

Comment: I see no parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote paths with spaces.

```
cd "C:\Program Files\etc"
```